# Digital or Analog laundry washing machine

Tags: washing-machine, laundry

I've been searching for a used washing machine, and sellers always mention if it's digital or analog.

What's the difference between one and the other? Is there one that's better than the other?

In terms of price in the used market, they're more or less the same at around USD$300-$400.

Comment: Analog are the good type old style of turning knobs.  Digital is a lot of useless buttons that just confuse you and break often.

Comment: @crip659,  LOL...I wanted to say that but didn't want to come off as a cranky old guy...but it's all true.

Comment: @RMDman  If we cannot be cranky old guys, what we are good for.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly the controls. Mechanical timer with dials and switches versus small computer chip with keyboard. Theoretically the computer permits fancier features, but the old clock-timer approach has run reliably for generations...

Comment: And still running.  I am scared if I have to replace one of them with new stuff.  Might save money running the new stuff, but figure replacement cost every few years will cancel that fast.

Comment: Electronics has become more reliable too. Software I'm less certain of, but...